# Passing variable value to another user's shell

Tags: shell, environment-variables

Below is a simple script `a.sh`

```
#name: a.sh
user=$(whoami)
sudo runuser -l test2 -c 'touch /home/test2/$user.file'
```

I am trying to save the current user's user name which is `test1` in variable `user` and make a file in `/home/test2` directory as user `test2`. The scripts returns with no error but makes no file named `test1.file` in `/home/test2`. After a bit looking around I found that there is a file named `.file` in `/home/test2`. That means after going to `test2`'s shell environment the `$user` variable is not getting resolved.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expansion of `$user` on the `sudo` command line is happening just before the `touch` command executes.  In the environment which is active at that point in time (which most likely has been cleared by `sudo`), its value is undefined and therefore expands to the empty string.  This is where you get the file called `.file` from.

To create the file with the proper name, use double quotes around the `touch` command.  This will ensure that `$user` is expanded *before* `sudo` is invoked:

```
sudo runuser -l test2 -c "touch /home/test2/$user.file"
```

Note: I don't know what `runuser` is. I would have used

```
sudo -u test2 touch "/home/test2/$user.file"
```